# Meteorjs and bootstrap3 modal rare behavior

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, attachedbehaviors

Im a newbee on Meteorjs and Im testing an implementation of FullCalendar and meteor, and I got a strange problem with this modal in particular. is a modal for edit, It is supposed to trigger when you click on a list of links of events wich I successfuly test on other apps in the pass, I already have another modal for create events on this view and works fine. but in this case, it seems to not attach the js behavior correcly. **the modal is displayed**, *but no effects and not working the close nor the submit buttons*.

I wonder if in this particular case, Im losing something or some code tag or the FullCalendar is in conflict?, **and for any help Thank you**.

here is the demo deply on meteor.com [gbelot.todo3.meteor.com](http://gbelot.todo3.meteor.com/)

here is the code on gitHub: [https://github.com/gbelot2003/meteor-todo-bt3/blob/todo3-icalendar/client/home](https://github.com/gbelot2003/meteor-todo-bt3/tree/todo3-icalendar/client/home)

and here the controller and Templates code:

```
Meteor.subscribe("events");

 Template.body.rendered = function () {
    var fc = this.$('.fc');
    this.autorun(function () {
    Events.find();
    fc.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
 });
};

Template.calendarEdit.helpers({
  events: function(){
    var fc = $('.fc');
    return function (start, end, tz, callback) {
        //subscribe only to specified date range
        Meteor.subscribe('events', start, end, function () {
            //trigger event rendering when collection is downloaded
            fc.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        });

        var events = Events.find().map(function (it) {
            return {
                title: it.date,
                start: it.date,
                allDay: false
            };
        });
        callback(events);
    };
},

options: function() {
    return {
        id: 'myid2',
        class: 'myCalendars',
        lang: 'es',
        allDaySlot: false,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        axisFormat: 'h:mm a',
        timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'h:mm a',
            month: 'h:mm a',
            agendaWeek: 'h:mm a'
        },
        firstHour: 7,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: false,
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            callback(Events.find({}).fetch());
        },
        defaultView: 'month'
    };
 }
});

Template.HomeTemplate.onRendered(function(){
 var fc = this.$('.fc');
 this.autorun(function () { 
    Events.find();
    fc.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
 });
 this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss'
 });
});

 Template.HomeTemplate.events({
 'submit #new-event': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = event.target.title.value;
    var start = event.target.start.value;
    var end = event.target.end.value;
    var description = event.target.description.value;

    Meteor.call("addEvent", title, start, end, description);
    event.target.title.value = "";
    event.target.start.value = "";
    event.target.end.value = "";
    event.target.description.value = "";
    $("#createEvent").modal("hide");
 },

/** this modal works well **/
/***************************/
'click .create': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#createEvent").modal("show");
 }
});

Template.HomeTemplate.helpers({
 event: function(){
    return Events.find();
 }
});

Template.eventList.events({

 'click .delete': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    id = this._id;
    Meteor.call('deleteEvent', id);
},

 /**** here is the call for the modal *****/
 /** with problems. Did I miss something? */
 /******************************************/
 'click .update': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".updateModal").show();
 }
});
```

the homeTemplate here

```
<template name="HomeTemplate" id="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>Todos & FullCalendar Test</h2>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Full Calendar</h3>
            <!--<button class="refresh">Refresh</button>-->
            {{> calendarEdit }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Events todo App <a href="#" id="add-Event" class="create btn btn-Google pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></h3>

            <ul class="list-group">
                {{#transition in="zoomIn" out="bounceOut"}}
                    {{#each event}}
                        {{> eventList}}
                    {{/each}}
                {{/transition}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  {{> createEvent}}
  {{> updateModal}}
</template>
```

This is the Template where you click on link

```
<template name="eventList">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <a type="button" href="#" class="update">{{title}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default delete pull-right">  <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h4>
    <p>{{start}} | {{end}}</p>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{description}}</p>
 </li>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried it out on gbelot.todo3.meteor.com using Mac/Chrome. Could add events, esc-key to close dialog, submit etc... seemed to work fine. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Thank Michel, the problem is with the edit modal link, is not attach the javascript. just display the modal but no modal effects, creation is fine..!!

Comment: oh ok, I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

this has been solve by using peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal, that package did the job!!!